# with-compiler and extra-lib-dirs in cabal for ALL developers

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a typical stack project layout and I am transitioning to a cabal. The problem is that I should reference extra libraries and installed GHC compiler. My current solution is:

```
-- cabal.project file:
...
extra-lib-dirs: libs/mylib   -- libs/ is in the project root, where is the cabal file
```

and

```
-- cabal.project.local file:
with-compiler: /the/path/to/ghc/exe
```

The second setting works (compiler's location), but it has a problem: it is an absolute path relevant for A) my computer, B) my OS. But how to do it for all users of the project (they use other OSes and have other locations for GHC)?

Another problem is that relative `extra-library-dirs` worked for stack, but it does not work for cabal, I get an error that it must be an absolute path. When I changed it to be an absolute one, I built the project successfully but the path is relevant for my OS/file locations only.

Is it possible to replace these 2 settings with something that can be common for ALL developers and to be in our Git repository? I thought there is something `${projectroot}` but it seems no such placeholder. And I need some place-hodler for both settings. Or there is way to achieve common code-base for all developers using different OSes and file system layouts?

Comment: Why not (1) use `packages:` for the extra libs, (2) `with-compiler: ghc-X.Y.Z`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, I am very newbie with cabal, I used stack before :(  Could you post detailed answer how to do it, please? Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have a directory like this

```
cabal.project
libs
 |-my-lib
   |- my-lib.cabal
   |- ...
 |-my-other-lib
   |- my-other-lib.cabal
   |- ...
```

Then your `cabal.project` looks like this

```
packages: lib/my-lib
          lib/my-other-lib
with-compiler: ghc-8.10.7  
-- You can delete the line above and cabal will use the compiler in PATH to build the project. 
-- If you specify the version and developer doesn't have it on the PATH, then he/she should install it.
```

This information is directly taken from the [cabal users guide](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html). You should read it carefully as it is well written. Also, you can take a look to other haskell project and see how they do it. For example [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/cabal.project) or the [cardano node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/cabal.project)

Comment: @Ismor is it possible to do the same trick with `.so`/`.dll` file (which is not a package)?

Comment: do you mean like linking an external library? for example `vulkan` or something like that?. I don't really know. I imagine you can, since you can for example create a `C-lang` library and link it... but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Yes, C libraries, Go libraries, they are `.so` for Linux and `.dll` for Windows (we support multiple OSes). As I see the convenient way is to install them in standard paths and to hardcode these paths? I tried also another way: to copy shared objects to GHC dir `$MYGHC/lib64/ghc-9.2.3/base-4.16.2.0/` but it means that I must write some Makefile or similar where to "install" libs

Comment: I don't really know, but you can take a look to [sdl2 bindings](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2) which include `c` headers and other non-haskell elements.